# AVG of SSRS Report Column

Tags: reporting-services, expression

Using the function below to calculate the average of a column with numeric and text values, e.g. 3, 2.6, N/A

```
  AVG(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,Fields!Score.Value,"0")))
```

How do I calculate the average of **numeric values only** i.e. not sum and count text values?

Comment: That looks fine, did you use it in a parent group level or in the details level?

Comment: I did a Add Total in the parent group, the row with the expression sits below details row

Answer (score 0):

As you probably realised, you are including 0 for each instance where the value is not numeric. So if you have 10 values, and 3 are not numeric you are still dividing the total by 10. I can't test this at the moment but try these options.

1. Change the "0" to `nothing` (no quotes).
2. Work out the average the old fashioned way ! with

   SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,Fields!Score.Value,0))) / SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,1,0)))

Comment: tried both options, see below, but get value NaN displayed in some cells 1. AVG(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,Fields!Score.Value,Nothing))) 2. SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,Fields!Score.Value,Nothing))) / SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,1,Nothing)))

Comment: On the seconds option, use zero instead of nothing as per my original comment. If this still does not work, post a sample of your data and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for the leads, this finally worked                                                                                                                                                                                                                        =iif(SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,1,0)))=0,0,SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,Fields!Score.Value,Nothing))) / SUM(CInt(iif(IsNumeric(Fields!Score.Value)=True,1,0))))